# Covariance matrix of two equiprobable classes

Tags: probability, pca, covariance, covariance-matrix, kullback-leibler

Today in class the professor gave us the following question:

Two equiprobable classes with mean vectors `μ1 = [4, 2]^T` and `μ2 = [−4,−2]^T` respectively have an equal covariance matrix:

```
Φ = 3.5  1.5
    1.5  3.5
```

Determine which of the K-L axes generated by matrix contains most first order discriminatory information.

I do understand how to solve the equation the only thing I do not understand that he gave us a hint which is:

```
P(w1) = P(w2) = 0.5
```

and

```
Φ1 = 3  1    Φ2 = 4  2 
     1  3         2  4
```

If both classes have the same covariance matrix mentioned in the question. How come `Φ1` and `Φ2` have different values and how they were calculated? I have been trying to look for an explination in my book but cannot find anything related to that